# Animation in Vega/Lite

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I tried to implement an animation similar to the one showed in https://vimeo.com/177767802 (min 2:30)

My code is the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"A": 2,"B": 3,"C": 4,"D": "a"},
      {"A": 1,"B": 2,"C": 1,"D": "a"},
      {"A": 4,"B": 5,"C": 15,"D": "b"},
      {"A": 9,"B": 10,"C": 80,"D": "b"}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "circle",
  "select": {"id": {"type": "point","on": "mauseover"}},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "A","type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "B","type": "quantitative"},
    "color": [
      {"if": "id","field": "D","type": "nominal"},
      {"value": "grey"}
    ],
    "size": {"value": 100}
  },
  "config": {"mark": {"fillOpacity": 0.5}}
}
```

Essentially it is the same code as in the video,  with the only difference that I used a smaller data set which (I took from H. Wickham.)

I tried to render the plot using the Vega-Lite editor (https://vega.github.io/vega-editor/?mode=vega-lite&renderer=svg). The resulting scatterplot is correct, the circles are grey (as they should be), but it does not display any animation and the legend is broken.

My question is whether there is something wrong with the code,  something that I overlooked.  In case the code is right, but the problem is that I used Vega-Lite 1.0 instead of Vega-Lite 2.0  is there a way to use a Vega-Lite 2.0 (fully understanding the risks of using an alfa version code) in the Vega-Lite editor?

Answer (score 4):

It's now 2021, one may also check out [Gemini](https://github.com/uwdata/gemini) which aims to extend the grammar of data viz to some simple animations of **single-view** Vega/Vega-Lite charts

Comment: Or [Vizzu](http://vizzuhq.com/), which specifically made for animated visualizations.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Vega 3 and Vega-Lite 2 with selections at https://vega.github.io/editor. We will keep updating the deployed versions.

Answer (score 1):

Vega-lite does not currently support selection, though it will in the upcoming 2.0 release. This video is a preview of interactive functionality that will be available later this year.

Comment: Thanks,  I suspected so.  Do you have a time frame when vega-lite 2 will be available?

Comment: I've been told it will be some time this spring.